# Authentic Books for reference in Islamic eschatology

Tags: sunni, eschatology

Which books are authentic to refer and study Islamic eschatology?
for the reference of those Books related to the Author and authenticity.

Comment: You can read whole QUran, it itself contains all kind of proofs and happenings about the judgement day, when you are done reading that, i don't know what you mean by authentic, you can pick any authentic hadees book and go straight to the chapters related to the topic. When you reach thsi stage consider sunnah.com as starting point.

Answer (score 1):

One of these books might be:

al-Tadhkirah fī Aḥwāl al-Mawtá wa-Umūr al-Ākhirah التذكرة في أحوال الموتى وأمور الآخرة (Reminder of the Conditions of the Dead and the Matters of the Hereafter): a book dealing with the topics of death, the punishments of the grave, the endtimes and the day of resurrection of [Imam al-Qurtobi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Al-Qurtubi)

Beside
al-Budur as-Safirah fi ahwal al-Akhirah البدور السافرة في أحوال الآخرة of [Imam as-Suyuti](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Al-Suyuti) (not one of his better works as it seems).

and
al-Bohor az-Zakhirah fi 'ulumi al-Akhirah "البحور الزاخرة في علوم الآخرة
of as-Safaryani [محمد بن أحمد السفاريني](https://ar.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D9%85%D8%AD%D9%85%D8%AF_%D8%A8%D9%86_%D8%A3%D8%AD%D9%85%D8%AF_%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B3%D9%81%D8%A7%D8%B1%D9%8A%D9%86%D9%8A)

If you could make clear what topics these books should address I could try to give you a more detailed list see also [this fatwa](https://www.islamweb.net/ar/fatwa/194067) (in Arabic) on a book reference on the topic.